# How to detect one date field value is later/greater than the other date field?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have **one textbox(displays count result)**, **one button(performs the counting)**, **and two DateTimePickers(for date period from and to)** in a form. I am using MS Access database for my program with **two date fields(date1 and date2)**. What I want is to count how many records dated with(dates given from **datetimepickerfrom and datetimepickerto)**. The counting is with condition like: **If date2 is greater or later than date1 then the counting will base on date2, else on date1**. Any suggestion or modification in my code is highly appreciated.

This is my code but it results error:"Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal."

````
countingconnection()
     countrec = New ADODB.Recordset
     With countrec

If .Fields("Date2").Value > .Fields("Date1").Value Then
 .Open("select count(*) as count2 from Docstable where Date2 >=#" & DateTimePickerfrom.Value.Date & "# and Date2 <=#" & DateTimePickerto.Value.Date & "#", countcon, 2, 3)
         textbox1.Text = .Fields("count2").Value
         .Close()
else
    .Open("select count(*) as count1 from Docstable where Date1 >=#" & DateTimePickerfrom.Value.Date & "# and Date1 <=#" & DateTimePickerto.Value.Date & "#", countcon, 2, 3)
         textbox1.Text = .Fields("count1").Value
         .Close()

end if

End With```
````

Comment: I guess you don't have any _field_ information before you actually _open_ the recordset.

Comment: You should be doing the comparison, filtering and counting in SQL and using ADO.NET to get a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what that would look like done purely in SQL and using ADO.NET:

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT COUNT (*)
           WHERE (Date1 >= Date2 AND Date1 BETWEEN @DateFrom1 AND @DateTo1)
           OR (Date2 > Date1 AND Date2 BETWEEN @DateFrom2 AND @DateTo2)"
Dim dateFrom = DatePickerFrom.Value.Date
Dim dateTo = DatePickerTo.Value.Date
Dim count As Integer

Using connection As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
    With command.Parameters
        .Add("@DateFrom1", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom
        .Add("@DateFrom2", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom
        .Add("@DateTo1", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTo
        .Add("@DateTo2", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTo
    End With

    connection.Open()

    count = CInt(command.ExecuteScalar())
End Using
```

Unfortunately, the Jet and ACE providers don't properly support named parameters so you have to add each date value twice.

EDIT:

You posted on another site that you're using VB 2012 but here you say VB 2010. It may not matter as VB 2012 may be the same but I'm fairly sure that VB 2010 doesn't support multiline `String` literals. In that case, you can use an XML literal instead:

```vb
Dim sql = <sql>
              SELECT COUNT (*)
              WHERE (Date1 >= Date2 AND Date1 BETWEEN @DateFrom1 AND @DateTo1)
              OR (Date2 > Date1 AND Date2 BETWEEN @DateFrom2 AND @DateTo2)
          </sql>
'...

Using connection As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New OleDbCommand(sql.Value, connection)
    '...
End Using
```